# Check whether a thread already owns a mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have a function that needs to be accessed atomically using a mutex. However, the thread calling this function might already own the mutex. How can i check whether i already have the mutex locked by the calling thread?

```
        void Stop() {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // if thread already owns the mutex, skip this
            active = false;
            cond_var.notify_all();
        }
```

Comment: Is using a [recursive_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) acceptable?

Comment: There is no way to query if a `std::mutex` is already owned by the calling thread. That is why `std::recursive_mutex` exists, so the calling thread doesn't have to worry about this, it can lock the mutex as many times as it needs, it just needs to unlock each successful lock so other threads will be able to lock it.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i was looking for! Also had to change my `std::condition_variable` to `std::condition_variable_any` and everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: In general, needing to figure out whether you already hold a mutex indicates a design problem. Yes, you can hack around it with a recursive mutex, and, I suppose, that's occasionally actually necessary. But a clean design, with a well-defined thread-safe interface that handles the locking, can remove the need. Split `Stop` into two functions, one that just assigns to `active` and notifies the condition variable, and another that locks the mutex and calls the first.

Comment: An addendum to Pete Becker's comment: mutex locks are best kept very short to prevent a program that locks the mutex frequently from effectively serializing itself and being slower than a single threaded approach. If you are stacking function calls deep enough that you don't know the state of the mutex, odds are good you're locking too long and will have to rethink your algorithm.